# Trying to load a file platform independent

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I am trying to open a file platform independent in this way:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("/opt/sampleFile.jasper");
```

In linux all is right but in windows I am getting the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \opt\sampleFile.jasper
```

In windows I am locating this file in c:\opt\

What is wrong?

Comment: Does the file/directory exist?

Comment: Yes @Reimeus, the directory and the file exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the default drive for your application?  `/opt/` will be `C:/opt/` on Windows if this is the drive of your current working directory.

Instead of storing data in a system directory like `/opt` I would use a directory relative to the user's home directory i.e. `System.getProperty("user.home")`

Comment: I have tried my example in another apps without problem. I really don't know why it is not working right now

Comment: @JohnB Do you have more than one drive?

Comment: I have one drive and tow partitions (two letters: c and d)

Comment: @JohnB so if you application is running on the `D` drive `/opt/` will be `D:/opt/` but use the same path in a program running on the `C` drive and it will be `C:/opt/`  Try printing `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to see the working directory.